Ubuntu 24.04 general graphics malaise
After each OS upgrade, I expect a few problems. However with 24.04, I've had more and more issues with graphical things not working.

Thunderbird can't save message attachments.
Thunderbird can't open a popup to SaveAs an attachment.
Firefox no longer restarts by opening its windows on the same desktop/workspace that it was on the last time Firefox closed. Instead, all the FF windows open on the current desktop/workspace.
Gnome Extensions window won't open when the dock button is clicked. Other apps in the dock open properly.
After suspending my laptop, it doesn't restore properly, if at all. Sometimes I have to switch to a console window, kill my running applications, then reboot. Sometimes the display shows only some of the characters in my login name. Just logging out and back in doesn't work. That results in a message that essentially says "reboot"
Display dim/brighten no longer works from the function keys or from the command line.

Versions:

Gnome Shell 46.0
Ubuntu 24.04


I don't see a question here only a thinly disguised rant. Please read [ask] then [edit] accordingly

I understand. I'm trying not to rant. All these problems seem to be related to all these programs not being able to open dialog windows or talk to whatever creates the dialog windows or dims/brightens the screen. How am I supposed to know what package is responsible? I don't get error messages. I don't get a "core" dump. When I report the problem to Mozilla, they say it's not their problem. I don't know how to tell if it's the nVidia driver or something in Ubuntu.

Installing the Ubuntu drivers, which included a newer nVidia driver, fixed the problem!
